# Create a file descriptor in ruby

Tags: ruby, text-parsing

I am writing a script will perform various tasks with DSV or positional files. These tasks varies and are like creating an DB table for the file, or creating a shell script for parsing it.

As I have idealized my script would receive a "descriptor" as input to perform its tasks. It then would parse this descriptor and perform its tasks accordingly.

I came up with some ideas on how to specify the descriptor file, but didn't really manage to get something robust - probably due my inexperience in ruby.

It seems though, the best way to parse the descriptor would be using ruby language itself and then somehow catch parsing exceptions to turn into something more relevant to the context.

Example:

The file I will be reading looks like (`myfile.dsv`):

```
jhon,12343535,27/04/1984
dave,53245265,30/03/1977
...
```

Descriptor file `myfile.des` contains:

```
FILE_TYPE = "DSV"
DSV_SEPARATOR = ","

FIELDS = [
    name => [:pos => 0, :type => "string"],
    phone => [:pos => 1, :type => "number"],
    birthdate => [:pos => 2, :type => "date", :mask = "dd/mm/yyyy"]
]
```

And the usage should be:

```
ruby script.rb myfile.des --task GenerateTable
```

So the program `script.rb` should load and parse the descriptor `myfile.des` and perform whatever tasks accordingly.

Any ideas on how to perform this?

Comment: Why not use a configuration file format like [YAML](http://yaml.org/) or [JSON](http://www.json.org/) instead of trying to load in arbitrary Ruby code? Declaring global constants leads to quite a mess if you make a habit of it.

Comment: Another option would be a DSL, i.e. instead of declaring constants, you would call methods: `file_type "DSV"` where `file_type` is a method

Comment: "File descriptor" really means something else. What you seem to be after is a configuration or resource file.

Comment: Hey guys. No reason at all to not use these options apart from not knowing them. Will check them all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use YAML

Instead of rolling your own, use [YAML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) from the standard library.

### Sample YAML File

Name your file something like *descriptor.yml*, and fill it with:

```
---
:file_type: DSV
:dsv_separator: ","
:fields:
  :name:
    :pos: 0
    :type: string
  :phone:
    :pos: 1
    :type: number
  :birthdate:
    :pos: 2
    :type: date
    :mask: dd/mm/yyyy
```

### Loading YAML

You can read your configuration back in with:

```
require 'yaml'
settings = YAML.load_file 'descriptor.yml'
```

This will return a *settings* [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) like:

```
{:file_type=>"DSV",
 :dsv_separator=>",",
 :fields=>
  {:name=>{:pos=>0, :type=>"string"},
   :phone=>{:pos=>1, :type=>"number"},
   :birthdate=>{:pos=>2, :type=>"date", :mask=>"dd/mm/yyyy"}}}
```

which you can then access as needed to configure your application.